# Crystal Report is automatically (randomly) adding white space after a sequence of text X's before a number in a field. Want to prevent the whitespace

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a field that I'm sure does not have white space in it at a certain location, but for some reason Crystal Reports is automatically adding space to the field but only after X's in certain scenarios. This is a text field which I'm sure is pulling down from a text field in the db as well.

This is hard to explain without a pictured example, so here's what I mean:

[Random Spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd9I3.png)

As you can see, there is whitespace after the X's. it should not be there, as this is not what is coming from the db. And strangely, when copy/pasted from the report, there is no white space either! Here it is when copy/pasted straight from the report:

"Test 15dig w spaces XXXXXXXXXXX2345"

Why is this occurring, and how can it be corrected? Currently there is no real formula for the field, it is just taking whatever it coming from the db straight into that field. The whitespace is being added automatically somehow, and I'm not sure at all why.

Here is what I've tried: Have tried calling ToText on the field (even though it is already a text field).  Have also tried formatting the field in various different ways.  Tried asking on SAP forum but no help as of yet.

Comment: Think this is a BUG with Crystal Reports, as it only occurs after a long sequence of character X.  Tried with other characters and the whitespace was not there.

Answer (score 0):

Copy & Paste the text "Test 15dig w spaces XXXXXXXXXXX2345" into a text object in Crystal. Apply the same font and formatting (use the brush toolbar button to clone the formatting).

If you don't see the same strange space, the problem is due to non-printable characters in the database field. In that case, you can strip away such characters using a formula and the Replace() function.

Comment: I have tried this and the whitespace still remains, but only after long sequences with the character X.  I believe I have come across a bug in Crystal Reports and have notified them as such.